# CSS - Using table-footer-group with images

Tags: html, css

For the life of me I can't figure out why my image isn't accepting the **display: table-footer-group** property. It seems to work when I have a div wrapped inside of an image but just an image itself isn't working. The problem is I can't wrap the image within a div and have to use the following mark-up but have the image placed below the text. All I'm trying to do is place the image below the text but for the life of me can't get this to work. Any ideas?

JS Fiddle with div wrapper: http://jsfiddle.net/kSsAB/4/

JS Fiddle with just image: http://jsfiddle.net/ro5cprzz/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="label-below">
  <img alt="Some Text" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <span> Some Text </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.label-below{
 display: table;
}

img{
 display: table-footer-group;
}

span{
 display: table-row-group;
}
```

Comment: Not that I have an answer, but I have never attempted this without having all the elements I am table positioning be divs.

Answer (score 0):

With the following caveats:

1. Without a little more detail on what you are trying to do,
2. Why you have the restrictions you do,
3. Whether or not your image is a known size, and
4. How it needs to interact with the parent elements / the rest of the page.

You could accomplish this with absolute / relative positioning: http://jsfiddle.net/v4ek6crn/

**HTML**

```
<div class="label-below">
    <img alt="Some Text" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    <span> Some Text </span>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.label-below{
    position: relative;
}

img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right 0;
}

span{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 150px;
    right 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the delayed response. I have the restrictions that I do because the text as well as image (and sizes) are coming from a CMS and I don't have control over what they are uploading.

Comment: Just realized I asked the wrong question, you want the text on top - do you have a fixed amount of text or a fixed space you can allocate for text? If so this is easy with absolute / relative positioning.

Comment: Unfortunately not the text should just wrap to the next line so users can enter however much text they would like.

Comment: Ah - then I am out of ideas unless you can add divs around the img and span tags.